# How to use Autofac in seperate areas in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac, area

I am now working on source code regarding ecommerce. In this source code , brnmall.web is the web project, its admin platform is in library brnmall.web.storeadmin which is  registered in web project as area.

below is the brnmall.web:

[image]

below is the brnmall.web.storeadmin, registered as area in brnmall.web:

[image]

I want to use autofac in brnmall.web.storeadmin, so I add another global.asax in it, in the application_start method, I register all the controllers and components that I need.
but when I use the code below to trigger data

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var serviceTypeRepo = unitOfWork.Repository<BrnMall.DAL.Access.cha_servicetype>();
        var result = serviceTypeRepo.Get(x => x.serviceid == 1);
        ViewBag.result = result;
        return View();
    }
```

exception throw to me: ***"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'BrnMall.Web.Charging.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."***

Anyone have the same scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Is BrnMall.Web.StoreAdmin a seperate Web Application Project or an assembly project that is referenced by BrnMall.Web?

If StoreAdmin is just an Assembly referenced by BrnMall.Web and not a runnable Web Application on its own, then I believe you can remove the Seperate registrations and the global.asax in the StoreAdmin project, but I would replace these registrations with an AutofacModule registration class like below which will then register all your Controllers in that Assembly.

Then to wire it all up, you just need to have BrnMall.Web Autofac registration register your new module which will register Controllers in that assembly and any other components you decide to register there.

eg.

In your BrnMall.Web project....

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); //Register controllers in the Executing Assembly
        builder.RegisterModule<BrnMall.Web.StoreAdmin.AutofacModule>(); //Register the registrations in the StoreAdmin Autofac Module below.
        //Register any other components

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

And in your BrnMall.Web.StoreAdmin ...

```
using Autofac;

public class AutofacModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterControllers(ThisAssembly); //This will register any Controllers that are in this assembly
        //Register any other components that relate to this particular Project
    }
}
```

The benefit to registering Autofac Modules and referencing them is that you can specify in each project the registrations that belong to just that assembly which keeps the code a lot neater and all your registrations a lot neater.

I hope this helps?